# Firefox's Network Monitor does not show blocked requests

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

## Question

When I browse a web page, some requests are intentionally blocked by:

1. Firefox's [content blocking](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/content-blocking)
2. Addons (I use [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock))

However, those blocked requests are not shown in the Network Monitor at all. Is this a bug, or just an unfinished feature?

I ask the question because Chrome's Network Monitor **does** show blocked requests and labels them as **blocked**. Sometimes it is useful to navigate the details of requests even if they are not actually sent.

## Simple Example

1. Choose **Strict** for the content blocking settings.
2. Open the Network Monitor.
3. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/.

The site information will show that **www.google-analytics.com** is blocked, but the request will not be shown in the Network Monitor.

## My Platform

- OS: Windows 7
- Firefox: 68.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not implemented as of Firefox 68.

Some work on this was [completed for Firefox 69](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1157817), but there's a [follow-up bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1556451), which is still not fixed as of now.

Comment: OK. It seems that the only thing I can do now is to wait for the next release. Thank you for the information.